# Creating your own forms designer

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I would like start writing an application that will let my user design the interface by choosing some basic controls as Labels, TextBoxes etc. Once done I would like to save the layout in an xml file and be able later on runtime to reconstruct what user choose.

Is there anything similar ready and pre-made?
Can you suggest me the approach?

Any suggestion is welcome!

Cheers

Comment: Have you googled form designers? There are tons of professional tools both open source and proprietary that do this.  This isn't a programming question, and doesn't really belong here.  If you are asking this for windows environment, Microsoft Access and VB do that  in an extensive way.

Comment: Googling Form designers you get a ton of things. I would like to let my users to define their own interface via a designer. I would like to build it and I was asking for tips on where to start.

Comment: Start with a blank winforms project.

Comment: Your thought is straight forward, again this is NOT the right forum for it ... try programmers.stackexchange.com ;  To write a generic designer, well you can start with a web interface (look at what Content Management Systems do) and build it in that. But that's debatable. It's a vague question, because I don't know your use cases (and I don't want to know hehe). What you are asking to do has been done before, and will be done again, you need to investigate this yourself Google IS your friend.  No one can investigate it FOR you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating your own designer is a lot like building your own submarine in your basement.  Programmers tend to take the quality of the Winforms or WPF designers as a standard of measure.  Both are however the result of multi man-year efforts at Microsoft.  Reproducing their work from scratch is a daunting task.

Best thing to do is leverage what's already done by them.  Possible with the Winforms designer, [this magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx) is excellent to help you get started.  It is dated but I'm fairly sure it is still relevant, little has changed in Winforms in the past 6 years.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great link!